# É possível desabilitar a primary key de uma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Queria saber se é possível desativar uma primary key de uma tabela.
Vou explicar o motivo para desabilitar a primary key.
Tenho uma tabela B que possui uma foregein referente a tabela A, mais eu preciso deletar a tabela A sem ter que deletar a foregein da tabela B.
A tabela A foi criado com 999 registro, porem, do  registro 1 ate o registro 35 foram criado certo, mais do registro 36 ate o registro 998 foi pedido para deletar os registro reservado.

o script para criar a tabela

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME = 'Tabela A')

BEGIN  

delete from Tabela A

INSERT INTO Tabela A VALUES ('001','Administradora de Cartões Sicredi Ltda.',03106213000190)                
INSERT INTO Tabela A VALUES ('035','Administradora de Cartões Sicredi Ltda.(filial RS)',03106213000271)             
INSERT INTO Tabela A VALUES ('036','resevado',null)             
INSERT INTO Tabela A VALUES ('998','revervado',null) 
INSERT INTO Tabela A VALUES ('999','Outros',NULL)    
END 

GO
```

Alguém poder me ajudar para deletar esta tabela.

Comment: O que você precisa mesmo é remover a relação de *foreign key* da tabela A para a tabela B, não? Uma vez que essa relação (e.g., campo `idA` da tabela B referencia campo `id` da tabela A), você poderá remover quaisquer elementos da tabela A (assumindo que não exista outra relação FK com essa tabela).

Comment: Olha não sei se entendi errado, mais ao meu ver você precisar fazer um update para atualizar a Tabela 'B' com os registros corretos, ou seja, os registros de 1 a 35. Depois você pode deletar as informações que considera errada na Tabela 'A' que são os de 35 ao 998.

Comment: Value a dica Marconi, foi conversado com os outros programador e ficou definido que, e melhor dar um update e depois deletar os registro do 35 ate 998, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível sim desativar uma primary key. Vou utilizar uma tabela cliente como exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente(
    id_cliente int NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_cliente_id PRIMARY KEY (id_cliente);
)
```

O que está acontecendo a cima /\
Criei uma tabela chamada **cliente**, com os campos **id** e **nome**, e adicionei uma restrição a esta tabela chamada **pk_cliente_id** indicando que o campo **id_cliente** é uma chave primária. Para remover  a chave primaria basta dar um drop na constraint primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE cliente DROP CONSTRAINT pk_cliente_id
```

A mesma ideia vale para remover uma foreign key. Uma foreign key também é uma constraint.

Caso você não saiba o nome da constraint e esteja utilizando o SQL Server, a query abaixo lista todas as chaves primárias e estrangerias do banco de dados.

```
SELECT
KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'FK_Nome_Constraint'
, KCU1.TABLE_NAME AS 'FK_Nome_Tabela'
, KCU1.COLUMN_NAME AS 'FK_Nome_Coluna'
, FK.is_disabled AS 'FK_Esta_Desativada'
, KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'PK_Nome_Constraint_Referenciada'
, KCU2.TABLE_NAME AS 'PK_Nome_Tabela_Referenciada'
, KCU2.COLUMN_NAME AS 'PK_Nome_Coluna_Referenciada'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU1
ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2
ON KCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
AND KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION
JOIN sys.foreign_keys FK on FK.name = KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME
Order by
KCU1.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Isso não é desabilitar, isso é excluir.
tem como desabilitar?